# Windows App Graphics Design Considerations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm attempting to write a paint like app in C#/wpf to generate networks of pipes and nodes.  One of the needed features is changing the nodes' colors when the user clicks them or hovers his mouse over them (2 separate highlight colors).

Currently, I have the graphics code structured as follows:

I have a global list of nodes `Node.list` and a paint event that loops through the list and reads the coordinates of each node and places an ellipse at that value.  (there is an embedded winform panel to serve as the drawing surface, hence paint event not render) Clicking the drawing surface where a point doesn't exist already adds a new node to `Node.list` and then triggers the paint event.  Clicking it where it does exist brings up a menu where coordinates and other properties can be adjusted.  It also sets a `isHighlighted` bool property to true, in which the paint event's logic catches and draws the point in different colors.  Here's the paint event code:

```
Node nodes = new Node();                                  
        for (int q = 0; q < Node.list.Count; q += 1)
        {
            nodes = Node.list[q];
            if(Node.list[q].redHL) //Clicked
            {
                g.FillEllipse(black, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.xCord) - 8, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.yCord) - 8, 19, 19);
                g.FillEllipse(red, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.xCord) - 6, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.yCord) - 6, 15, 15);
            }

            else //Regular Nodes
            {                    
                g.FillEllipse(black, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.xCord) - 8, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.yCord) - 8, 19, 19);
                g.FillEllipse(yellow, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.xCord) - 6, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.yCord) - 6, 15, 15);
            }
            if (Node.list[q].yellowHL) //Hovered
            {                    
                g.FillEllipse(black, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.xCord) - 8, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.yCord) - 8, 19, 19);
                g.FillEllipse(blue, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.xCord) - 6, Convert.ToInt32(nodes.yCord) - 6, 15, 15);

            }
        }
```

This approach worked very well until I attempted to set up the code so that upon hovering over a point it would change colors.  The first thing I tried was placing an if statement in the mouse move event like so:

```
row = pointExists(e.X, e.Y);

if(row != -1)
   /* Highlight point */
   Node.list.Count[row].isHighlighted = true;
else
   /* unhighlight all points */
   for(u = 0; u > Node.list.Count; u += 1)
      Node.list[u].IsHighlighted = false;
```

This works... but it cause the screen to flash like crazy because the paint event is being triggered every single time the mouse is moved!

I tried to set up some logic so that only the first time the mouse leaves the region the paint event is triggered, and succeeded... sort of.  I went from the above to this franken-logic-statement:

```
            if (row != -1  )
            {
                if (Node.inRegion)
                {
                    Node.lastNode = row;                        
                    for (int u = 0; u < Node.list.Count; u += 1)
                        Node.list[u].yellowHL = false;
                    Node.list[row].yellowHL = true;
                    Node.inRegion = false;
                    Node.outRegion = true;                        
                    wfSurface.Invalidate();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Node.outRegion)
                {                        
                    if (Node.lastNode != 0)
                        Node.list[Node.lastNode].yellowHL = false;
                    Node.inRegion = true;
                    Node.outRegion = false;
                    wfSurface.Invalidate();
                }                    
            }
```

Not exactly terse.

The above worked until I had to start throwing in more logic.  When the user wants to draw a node I have to throw in other conditions like "has the user selected the start point of the link" that change what color/when nodes are highlighted.

Anyone have any ideas on how is best to go about this?  I tried checking out this guys method:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8494/DrawTools

but gave up shortly after 20 minutes of looking through his source (app was far too complex for my comprehension).  I think I may be going at this totally wrong... In the above article the guy mentioned using a hit test to check if the user had clicked on a drawn graphic.  I just queried the list of coordinates to see if a node had been drawn there already, somewhat of a hacky solution... there has to be a more intelligent way to go about this.

Thanks Guys,

Hunter

Comment: please post a screenshot. I might be able to give you a much better solution.

Comment: @HighCore Just put one in

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you embedding the WinForms panel?  A WPF-only solution may be more suitable, but there may be a legit reason for embedding it.

Comment: @WonkotheSane Mainly because of some legacy code... no reason I can't switch which seems to be the general consensus.